# Codeigniter view url?

Tags: codeigniter, file, uploading

i cal upload images to folder if i use absolute url.
but how to use absolute url?

```
function do_upload()
 {
  $config['upload_path'] = 'upload/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
  $config['max_size'] = '100';
  $config['max_width']  = '1024';
  $config['max_height']  = '768';

  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
  {
   $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

   $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
  } 
  else
  {
   $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

   $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
  }
 }
```

The above is my code for controller.
i try to upload, but i can't judge in which path the folder should be located? either it should be in root or in controller or in view?

Answer (score 0):

It should go in root.